# How to add asset image in app bar as an action icon in Flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

**Problem**
I am trying to add a logout image icon in appbar of flutter screen. I have created a asset folder and created directories images/icons/ and placed icons in them. 
I have mentioned them in pubspec.yaml file. 
I tried to implement a asset image in appbar but its not working.

**Code**

**pubspe.yaml**

```
    name: mtrack_notifications
    description: Flutter application for MTrack Notifications 

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      http: ^0.11.3+16
      shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"


    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter


    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:

      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true

      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      # assets:
      #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
      #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
      assets:
      - assets/images/icons/like.png
      - assets/images/icons/logout.png
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[Click to see the IDE screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCqOT.png)

**Appbar code**

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //build a form widget using the form key we created above
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(StringRef.appName),
            actions: [

          new Center(
          child:new Text(
            userName,
            textScaleFactor: 1.5,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )),
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
            tooltip: 'Closes application',
            onPressed: () => exit(0),
          ),

          new IconButton(
            icon: new Image.asset('images/icons/logout.png'),
            tooltip: 'Closes application',
            onPressed: () => exit(0),
          ),

            ],
          ),
```

Comment: You need to include the code of your appbar too.

Comment: Please check the screenshot link  and code updated.

Answer (score 69):

The problem is in your path you have supplied to your `IconButton`.

It should be like this.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/logout.png'),
        onPressed: () => exit(0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html) you need to include the full path like specified in `pubspec.yaml` of the asset in order to load it:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/icons/logout.png')
```

Comment: This overflows everything above appbar (even a battery icon, a signal bar icon and a clock).

Comment: @Watanabe.N you have to restrict the view with something. e.g. a scaffold.

Comment: yeah, it is in scaffold. I solved it by putting `Image` in  `Icon` or `IconButton`.

Answer (score 2):

you should give 2 space before '-' and 1 space after '-' for image location
specification.

```
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

   assets:
     - assets/images/icons/like.png
     - assets/images/icons/logout.png
```

Answer (score 2):

**its working all "icon : " properties**

**icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('images/list.png')),**

```
child: BottomNavigationBar(
          //add background color
          backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('images/list.png')),
              label: 'List',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              label: 'Consultation',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              label: 'Lab',
            ),
           
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

dont try to register all of your images in `pubspec.yaml` if you place the image inside folders folder, then you should register all folder. like this

you put an image : hero.png in folder Images inside folder Assets.
Assets>Images>hero.png

then you should write them in 'pubspec.yaml' under: 
'flutter: 
   assets:
   -Assets/Images/hero.png '